# How can I get a named variable to evaluate in excel 2019? I want its value to change from time to time

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2019

I prefer not to use VBA (trying to keep this simple). How can I get alpha to be evaluatable in the enclosed excel snapshot? Thank you. MM
[image]

Comment: is the cell set to Text?  Are you showing your formulas IE `ctrl-~`?  Is there a space or `'` before the `=`?  There are a myriad of reasons this would be the case.

Comment: It is cell d8 I am trying to evaluate; it references cell c8.    What is in column D is centered.

Comment: I have given you a few possible reasons,  Make sure the cell is formatted as general or number and not text.  Make sure there are no spaces or `'` in front of the `=` in the formula bar.  If none of those work try hitting ctrl-`

Comment: Thanks. The cell was not formatted as a number. Big surprise as the number above it was.